# Upgraded to 13.10 and Files Are Gone But Showed up In Search

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 13.10 and everything was erased. I chose the upgrade option to "keep my personal files" and I was able to find one by searching. It was a document but was not in the new documents folder. So are the files still out there?

Update, what I didn't realize at the time was that this upgrade created a new user directory in Home folder. So the the original directory for the user "Joe" was sitting beside the new home directory folder for "Joseph".

So, Joe's files were still accessible, but a new admin user was created in the process.

Comment: Easy, just recover from the recommended backup you were advised to perform.

Comment: @K7AAY, FYI, I was curious why the files were still accessible if they had apparently been erased. I wanted to make sure there weren't a few GBs worth of files that were apparently hidden. But they weren't hidden, it looks like the upgrade created a new user with a fresh Home directory.

Comment: I explained the situation poorly. The content of the question was concerned with the _location_ of the files but not necessarily recovery of the files. Files weren't critical, just didn't want them taking up space if they were hidden. (But they weren't hidden.)

Answer (score 0):

if the files are hidden press ctrl + h it will show.
if it don't appear try to see it from terminal 
command :: ls -all 
if it doesn't please tell me i will try to search for you about this problem

Comment: Thank you but ctrl + h didn't work. and I got "command not found" for :: ls -all. If it helps I'll just let you know I'm trying to recover a printer driver.

Comment: I know I can easily reinstall the driver, I'm just curious to know if these hidden files might cause a conflict as I continue to use the computer. Do you advise I erase and reinstall to make sure?